# Разбить набор символов на два по знаку _ регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как разбить данный текст на два
TeksTr123_rewT8enf
по нижнему подчёркиванию  с помощью регулярного выражения. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значение первой группы — то, что до `_`, второй — после:

```
([^_]+)_([^_]+)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/593dt

Если после первого `_` текст может также содержать `_`, то вместо второго `[^_]` ставьте `.` просто.